# Save window binding in svelte store

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-3, svelte-store

Hi nice people of the Internet,

I created a listener for the scroll position of the user:
`<svelte:window bind:scrollY={y} />`
I would like to save this variable in a store, to make it accessible throughout the website. But for that I would need a setter. Is there a good performant way to do this?

I tried this, but it does not work:

````
  $: () => scrollPos.set(y);
  $: console.log("LOG: scrollPos", $scrollPos);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
<script>
import { y } from './store.js';
import LogScrollPosition from './LogScrollPosition.svelte';

let scrollY;
$: y.set(scrollY);
</script>

<button on:click={() => scrollY = 200}>
    Go down
</button>

<h1>Hello!</h1>

<LogScrollPosition />

<p>
Vestibulum arcu turpis, condimentum non lorem quis, volutpat laoreet turpis. Praesent euismod, libero eu pulvinar imperdiet, dolor ex molestie lacus, sed egestas arcu felis non libero. Aenean laoreet arcu porttitor dolor pulvinar eleifend. Pellentesque lacinia neque sit amet nulla blandit, at ullamcorper orci ultricies. Cras pulvinar nec est sit amet sollicitudin. Sed luctus massa nibh, eu luctus magna tincidunt vel. Morbi tempor velit elit, nec cursus risus pellentesque quis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus tristique lacus vel lorem lacinia, a accumsan turpis gravida. Maecenas dapibus gravida mauris, iaculis placerat urna rhoncus at. Vivamus vel malesuada nisi. Suspendisse pulvinar pellentesque lectus, non imperdiet nisi tempus sed. Maecenas vel magna eu diam faucibus semper ut nec neque.

Aliquam malesuada gravida libero, sit amet pellentesque felis viverra vel. Maecenas est tortor, eleifend ut est nec, maximus vehicula eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tincidunt fringilla urna id fermentum. Proin rhoncus iaculis ipsum. In a sapien sapien. Sed eget justo ac turpis sodales imperdiet. In condimentum mauris ut ex sagittis, id malesuada ligula dictum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Vivamus volutpat id velit et vehicula. Vivamus lectus orci, aliquam a maximus et, rhoncus in nibh. Etiam interdum sagittis justo et scelerisque. Quisque dapibus pulvinar pulvinar. Curabitur pulvinar, odio id eleifend consequat, sapien nulla congue metus, ut porttitor massa ipsum eget mauris. Duis a facilisis velit, non semper massa. Vestibulum semper velit nisi, sit amet blandit eros consectetur sit amet. Morbi accumsan magna a ex tempus imperdiet. Duis vitae convallis ipsum, imperdiet efficitur magna. Praesent ultrices turpis nec enim molestie, non aliquet tellus luctus. Sed porttitor nibh sit amet metus malesuada imperdiet et vitae ligula. Donec sit amet ullamcorper nisl. Nulla rhoncus ligula non tellus finibus efficitur. Nullam accumsan mattis risus at cursus. Duis ligula ligula, ullamcorper ac risus nec, hendrerit vulputate massa.

Phasellus pellentesque mauris ligula, id dapibus nisi lobortis a. In eget quam tincidunt, mattis ante eu, dignissim nisl. Proin sollicitudin dolor porttitor, tincidunt ipsum at, consequat leo. Morbi consequat imperdiet mauris, sed maximus tellus venenatis ut. Vestibulum tempus nisi ac semper volutpat. Vivamus rhoncus augue eu erat aliquet sodales. Ut consequat sapien enim, in pulvinar mauris dapibus varius. In mi mi, aliquam vel ante eu, lobortis aliquet lorem. Donec vulputate ac lorem ac laoreet.
</p>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={scrollY} />
```

Essentially you were close, but don't make the function reactive with `$: () => ...`. Just do `$: scrollPos.set(y)`.

Here's an example [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0b25543c884d45a2980d6048590bb107?version=3.12.1).

Answer (score 5):

You *should* be able to just bind directly to a store value:

```html
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

    const y = writable(0);
</script>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={$y}/>
```

Unfortunately it turns out you've found a bug — that doesn't currently work, for whatever reason. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3832

Answer (score 1):

Reactive statements will be re-evaluated when the values they depend on change, so you could just make `scrollPos.set(y)` reactive and it will work as expected.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/102bf5ec1ee941208841e6d45d89afc5?version=3.12.1))**

```html
<svelte:window bind:scrollY={y} />

<script>
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

  let y;
  const scrollPos = writable(0);

  $: scrollPos.set(y);
</script>

<div style="height:1000px;">
  <h1 style="margin-top:200px;">{$scrollPos}</h1>
</div>
```